# Change the color of labels based on current record's value compared to the previous one

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to find a way to automatically change the color of the labels (to green if higher and red if less) in a chart when the value of the record is more or less than the value of the previous record.
I have a code that works if the value to compare is hard wired but I need to have a dynamic option.

Please find below the issues I'm trying to fix in the current code:
1. Compare the label value to the previous value (first value is compared to 0, if zero then black, otherwise red)
2. Change the color to red (255,0,0) and green (0,176,80) - currently it uses a theme color (don't know how to use RGB code)

```
Sub LabelFontColor()
Dim ser As Series
Dim ser_vals As Variant
Dim num As Integer

Set ser = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
ser_vals = ser.Values

For num = LBound(ser_vals) To UBound(ser_vals)
    With ser.Points(num).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
        If ser_vals(num) > 0.15 Then 'tried ser_vals(num-1) but it didn't work
            .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
        Else
            .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
        End If
    End With
Next num
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't do "- 1" is the first comparison has nothing lower than it. What you need is a separate variable for tracking the last value.

I also added the RGB color codes you wanted:

```
Public Sub LabelFontColor()
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim ser_vals As Variant
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim previousVal As Variant

    Set ser = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    ser_vals = ser.Values
    previousVal = 0

    For num = LBound(ser_vals) To UBound(ser_vals)
        With ser.Points(num).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
            If ser_vals(num) > previousVal Then  'tried ser_vals(num-1) but it didn't work
                .RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            Else
                .RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End With

        previousVal = ser_vals(num)
    Next num
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply @Hackslash!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were on the right track with -1 however it probably failed on the first row, try something like this:

```
Sub LabelFontColor()
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim ser_vals As Variant
    Dim num As Integer

    Set ser = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    ser_vals = ser.Values

    For num = LBound(ser_vals) To UBound(ser_vals)
        With ser.Points(num).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
            If num > LBound(ser_vals) Then
                If ser_vals(num) > ser_vals(num - 1) Then
                    .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
                Else
                    .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
                End If
            Else
                .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
            End If
        End With
    Next num
End Sub
```

Comment: @Art glad I could help